# Javascript: pattern HREF needs to be replaced

Tags: javascript

Suppose on my HTML page I have many `href`s to a link.

Using Javascript, I need to loop through all `href`s and replace them with something and I don't have any ids to a `href`.

Please help.

Comment: Let's *not* suppose; let's, instead, see your actual mark-up, and how about telling us under what criteria you would judge one `href` to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var anchors = document.anchors;
for(var i=0,len=anchors.length;i<len;i++){
   anchors[i].href = 'some_new_url';;
}
```

**Edit** (after OP's comment)

document.anchors return anchors collection provide anchors have `name` attribute in them.

These are `valid` anchors for `document.anchors`

```
   <a href='http://www.link1.html' name=''>Link1</a>
   <a href='link2.html' name=''>Link2</a>
```

But this is not,

```
<a href='link2.html'>Link2</a>
```

Better, use this instead

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0,len=anchors.length;i<len;i++){
    anchors[i].href = 'some_new_url';;
}
```

Comment: why not `for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++)` ?

Comment: @AdnanShammout properties are typically slower to resolve than local variables.

Comment: If Jack is not clear, at each iteration js engine would calculate `anchors.length` in your case, but in my case, it has the `length` in a variable. It wont make much difference in small loops, but its a good practise to follow.

Comment: when i m using alert(anchors[i].href); its not echoing the href value

Comment: May be because you are trying to access `anchors` before they are loaded. Put this code in body `onload` function. Or please share your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: <script>
function delayedCall()
{
   var anchors = document.anchors;
   for(var i=0,len=anchors.length;i<len;i++)
   {
   alert(anchors[i].href);
   }
}
window.onload = delayedCall;
</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.href; i++) {
anchors[i].href = 'new target';
}


</script>

...

<a href='link1.html'>Link1</a>
<a href='link2.html'>Link2</a>
```

**Edit :**
Just another way :

```
var length = document.links.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
document.links[i].href = 'new target';
}
```

Comment: You *should* store your properties in a variable.

Comment: `var len = document.links.length;`  ,,This would be great ??

Comment: when i m using alert(anchors[i].target); its not echoing the href value

Comment: @MathsGal , Don't know why alert is not working on jsfiddle , but i printed  hrefs in a div here...take a look : [http://jsfiddle.net/z3LGN/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/z3LGN/2/)